# Change PCB-mounted switch

Tags: pcb, switches

I have this Bi-Direction Switch:

---

[image: front of switch]

([Image source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jz9MNeQIuvZI3cRedb9SD1P4AbXfkhoe) - front of switch)

---

[image: back of switch]

([Image source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zO9r1fRuAT2Rfmthz15CPMGUgGLBMZuL) - back of switch)

---

I want to change the Button/Switch (I don't know the exact English word) to this one, for style reasons:

[image]

([Image source](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/1200x900/3220-01.jpg))

I can't find an explanation how the Button/Switch on the PCB works. Should I just try to solder the thing on there? Or would you recommend something else?

Comment: `bat handle toggle switch`

Comment: the original switch may be a DPDT type.  .... it is two switches side by side .... each group of 3 contacts is one switch .... the middle is the common contact ....  the contacts on either side are connected either one or the other ..... use an ohmmeter to verify

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find an explanation how the Button/Switch on the PCB works.
>   Should I just try to solder the thing on there? Or would you recommend
>   something else?

Get an ohm meter and find out which [pins of the switch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jegykkfW2RA) are connected to which. Then toggle the switch and ohm again. You might also be able to do this for the switch in the PCB while in circuit. If they match then great, you have a replacement.